# How much read/write capacity I consume per query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

On DynamoDB read write capacity changes according to various factors and it is tedious and error prone to calculate it myself on each query. So I want to get capacity that I consume per query. Is there any API method to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query), you'll see there is a `ReturnConsumedCapacity` attribute you can pass as part of your query. You will get back the consumed capacity in your query response.